# Unable to resolve a bean for 'javax.persistence.EntityManager'

Tags: spring-boot

I had an embedded project, this was a war, I configured Spring Boot and this was deployed sucessfully on Wildfly 13.

My problem is that I moved the repositories and services of Spring Boot to another module, another jar, and from the web application, I added the dependency to this jar. I changed the package name of the classes,  the EntityScan and the ComponentScan to the new packages, but I am having the same error.

The goal is to deploy sucessfully my web application on Wildfly 13 using this component separated, the business logic.

I am running this on Java 8, Wildfly 13, Maven 3.3.9 and Spring Boot 2.1.2.RELEASE.

I've tried a lot of suggestions in the Internet, but I coudn't.

**This class I put in the jar separated to the web application:**

```java
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"io.quarzo.service"})
@EntityScan(basePackages = "io.quarzo.domain.model.entities")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "io.quarzo.service", entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactory")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class RepositoryConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public DataSource jndiDataSource() throws IllegalArgumentException, NamingException {
        JndiObjectFactoryBean bean = new JndiObjectFactoryBean();
        bean.setJndiName("java:/QuarzoDs");
        bean.setProxyInterface(DataSource.class);
        bean.setLookupOnStartup(true);
        bean.afterPropertiesSet();
        return (DataSource) bean.getObject();
    }

}
```

**This class I put in the web application:**

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class QuarzoApiApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(QuarzoApiApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(applicationClass);
    }

    private static Class<QuarzoApiApplication> applicationClass = QuarzoApiApplication.class;

}

@RestController
class HelloController {

    @Autowired
    private IBuserServiceImp buserService;

    @RequestMapping("/hello/{name}")
    String hello(@PathVariable String name) {
        return "Hi ------***--- " + buserService.findAll() + " !";
    }
}
```

**pom.xml in the jar file:**

```
<dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarzo.web</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarzo-domain</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.10.Final</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.6</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>
```

**pom.xml of the web application:**

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarzo.web</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarzo-service</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarzo.web</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarzo-domain</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

The stacktrace is too large, but I cut the messages:

```
14:57:54,857 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 3) WFLYSRV0014: Replacement of deployment "quarzo-api.war" by deployment "quarzo-api.war" was rolled back with the following failure message:

{                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    "WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"quarzo-api.war\".WeldStartService" => "Failed to start service                                                                                     
    Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DefinitionException: Exception List with 1 exceptions:                                                                                                                    
Exception 0 :                                                                                                                                                                                                      
javax.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Unable to resolve a bean for 'javax.persistence.EntityManager' with qualifiers [@javax.enterprise.inject.Default(), @javax.enterprise.inject.Any()].       
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.cdi.JpaRepositoryExtension.createRepositoryBean(JpaRepositoryExtension.java:120)                                                                                
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.cdi.JpaRepositoryExtension.afterBeanDiscovery(JpaRepositoryExtension.java:96)                                                                                   
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)                                                                                                                                             
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)                                                                                                                           
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)                                                                                                                   
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)                                                                                 
        at org.jboss.weld.injection.StaticMethodInjectionPoint.invoke(StaticMethodInjectionPoint.java:95)                                                                                                          
        at org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInvocationStrategy$SpecialParamPlusBeanManagerStrategy.invoke(MethodInvocationStrategy.java:144)
        at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:330)
        at org.jboss.weld.event.ExtensionObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ExtensionObserverMethodImpl.java:123)
        at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:308)
        at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:286)
        at org.jboss.weld.util.Observers.notify(Observers.java:172)
        at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifySyncObservers(ObserverNotifier.java:285)
        at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notify(ObserverNotifier.java:273)
        at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.fireEvent(ObserverNotifier.java:177)
        at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.fireEvent(ObserverNotifier.java:171)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractContainerEvent.fire(AbstractContainerEvent.java:53)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractDefinitionContainerEvent.fire(AbstractDefinitionContainerEvent.java:44)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AfterBeanDiscoveryImpl.fire(AfterBeanDiscoveryImpl.java:75)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup.deployBeans(WeldStartup.java:456)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.deployBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:86)
        at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldStartService.start(WeldStartService.java:96)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1736)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1698)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1556)
        at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1985)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1487)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1378)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
"},
    "WFLYCTL0288: One or more services were unable to start due to one or more indirect dependencies not being available." => {
        "Services that were unable to start:" => [
"jboss.deployment.unit.\"quarzo-api.war\".CdiValidatorFactoryService",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"quarzo-api.war\".component.\"com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener\".WeldInstantiator",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"quarzo-api.war\".component.\"javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag\".WeldInstantiator",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"quarzo-api.war\".component.\"javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.PermittedTaglibsTLV\".WeldInstantiator",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"quarzo-api.war\".component.\"javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.ScriptFreeTLV\".WeldInstantiator",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"quarzo-api.war\".component.\"org.jboss.weld.module.web.servlet.WeldInitialListener\".WeldInstantiator",
.
.
.
],
        "Services that may be the cause:" => [
            "jboss.clustering.web.route.default-server",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"quarzo-api.war\".component.\"com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"quarzo-api.war\".component.\"com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener\".WeldInstantiator",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"quarzo-api.war\".component.\"javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag\".START",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"quarzo-api.war\".component.\"javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag\".WeldInstantiator",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"quarzo-api.war\".component.\"javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.PermittedTaglibsTLV\".START",
.
.
.
"org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-container.web",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-container-configuration.hibernate",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-container-configuration.hibernate.transport",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-container-configuration.server",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-container-configuration.server.transport",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-container-configuration.web",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-container-configuration.web.transport",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.default-cache.ejb",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.default-cache.web",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.default-cache-configuration.server",
            "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.default-cache-configuration.web"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Milton, I highly suggest you paste the stacktrace for debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I solved this, the problem was I had a beans.xml in my jar project. I deleted the beans.xml and it works**